# RichFaces comboBox/suggestionBox rerender-problem

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm having some problems with richfaces combobox/suggestionbox. Everything works fine when they're rendered along with the page, but as soon as I rerender the  they're contained in, they're not rendered and I get a JS-exception saying:

> Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9

(it looks like something in A4J.AJAX.XMLHttpRequest.updatePagePart is failing..)

Relevant part of code:

```
<a:outputPanel id="autoFillPanel">
    <a:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="#{myBean.renderAutofiller}">
        <h:inputText id="autofillInput" value="#{myBean.value}" />

        <rich:suggestionbox for="autofillInput" var="result"
            suggestionAction="#{myBean.autoCompleteFiller}">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{result}" />
            </h:column>
        </rich:suggestionbox>
    </a:outputPanel>
</a:outputPanel>
```

Any ideas? I haven't had this problem with any other components (h:inputTexts etc..)

Comment: Does this error happen in every browser?

Comment: Which version of Richfaces are you using?

Comment: I don't know if this will help but, Richfaces doesn't work properly in IE9 see http://community.jboss.org/thread/156720 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-9485. We had to patch it to get it working (see the links). We are still experiencing a few issues with the suggestionBox, such as the suggestions disappear if you try to use the scrollbars. Everything else seems ok for us so far in anything else other than IE9.

Comment: @reevesy Even rerendering the control?

Comment: Haven't had any specific problems re-rendering so far, but we don't have our suggestion box in a re-renderable panel. But I think you could be hitting IE9 issues,maybe?

Comment: @ereevesy: No, I haven't even tried IE (luckily we're a OSX only-company..) But I've noticed now that it works in most FF versions, but in Chrome and Safari I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with webkit implementation of document.importNode. To circumvent this problem you can use this little piece of javascript code on your template file:

```
if( /webkit/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ){
    var _importNode = window.document.importNode;
    window.document.importNode = function(node, deep){
        try{
            return _importNode.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e) {
            if( e.code == DOMException.NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR ){
                // clone and adopt
                return document.adoptNode(node.cloneNode(deep));
            }
            throw e;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when this question is *old* , i ran into the same problem and solved it in our application.

We have the same setup: Richfaces 3.3.3, IE9, modified Ajax.js to allow IE9 run in native mode instead of emulating IE7.

in suggestionbox.js, there is a workaround for IE to keep the focus: (line 126++)

```
//IE only 
        if (RichFaces.navigatorType() == RichFaces.MSIE) {
            Event.observe(this.element, "focusout", function(event) {
                //in IE8+ , event.toElement is no longer supported for focusout
                var elt = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget; //CHANGE HERE
                while (elt) {
                    if (elt == this.update) {
                        this.element.keepFocus = true;
                        elt = undefined;
                    } else {
                        elt = elt.parentNode;
                    }
                }
            }.bindAsEventListener(this));
        }
```

With the change i marked, the code runs fine in IE9 for me, and scrolling with the scrollbar is possible again.